# The closure of a set A is the union of A and the derived set of A?

Tags: general-topology

I'm having trouble understanding why

$\bar A = A \cup A'$, where $A\subseteq\mathbb R^n$, $\space\bar A$ is the closure of $A$ , and $A'$ is the derived set of $A$.

EDIT: Here are some definitions I am working with:

(i) *Definition of adherent point*- Let $S \subseteq \mathbb R^n $, and $x$ a point in $\mathbb R^n$, not necessarily in $S$. Then $x$ is a **adherent** to $S$ if every ball n-ball $B(x;r)$ contains at least one point of $S$.

(ii) A set $S \subseteq \mathbb R^n $ is closed, if and only if, it contains all its adherent points.

(iii) The closure of a set $S$ is the set $\bar S = \{ x \in \mathbb R^n \space | \space \forall r>0, B(x;r)\cap S\ne \emptyset \}$

Comment: What is your definition of closure?

Comment: The closure of a subset of a topological space is the subset itself plus all of its limit points. That's exactly $A\cup A^\prime$, so this is a mere definition.

Comment: It's not a theorem, it's the definition of a closure.

Comment: @B.Pasternak Another common definition is that it is the intersection of all closed sets containing $A$

Comment: @eepperly16 True, but let's use the Axiom of Choice to choose this as our definition..

Comment: @B.Pasternak First of all, how does this involve the Axiom of Choice? Second, of the two definitions, which do you think is the most probable that the OP has? The one where the solution is "This is the actual definition, so it's clearly true", or one that actually requires some work?

Comment: @B.Pasternak There are many ways one may define the closure of a topological space.

Comment: @Arthur Are you kidding me? Mentioning the AoC was clearly meant as a pun.

Comment: @Arthur  Second of all, I'm not going to start guessing which definition the OP has, but I'll certainly pose that this is a commonly used definition. Then hopefully the OP will realize that he or she just should state the definition that he or she uses, and then we can talk about how they are all equivalent (if this is what the OP in fact wants; once again, from the question alone it's not at all clear, and I'd rather poke the bear than ask it questions, since this should trigger some thinking on the OP's part, which will inspire the right question.)

Comment: @Math1000 Come on guys, instead of telling me that there are many ways of defining what the closure of a (subset of a, btw) topological space is, focus on the OP's question. In addition, I said A mere definition, not THE definition.

Comment: Anyways, for the OP: if you could tell us what your definition of closure is, then perhaps you will get an answer or an explanation.

Comment: Just included some definitions that I've been given. Hopefully this makes things clearer.

Answer (score 1):

First show $A\cup A' \subseteq \overline A$.

Now assume $x \in \overline A$.  If x not in A' then
there is some open U nhood x with $U \cap A = \{x\}$.
Thus x in A.  Equality follows.

This is true of all topological spaces including R.
Looking for a solution to a homework problem is not research.